# Updating table with sum of selected values from that table itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `tmp_addit`  which looks like this

```
addition_id   allowance_id    sal_id   amount
 --------------------------------------------
   1             4            1       300              
   2             5            1       400        
   3             6            1       200       
   4             4            2       300      
   5             5            2       250
   6             6            2       150
```

I want to update the table such that the `amount` with `allowance_id` in `(5,6)` must be added to  `allowance_id` = `4`. Eg: I want to get `900` as `amount` for  (`sal_id` = `1` and `allowance_id` = `4`).

I tried this code but it's not working

```
 update tmp_addit set amount =(select sum(amount) from  tmp_addit  
 where allowance_id in(5,6)
 group by salary_id) where allowance_id=4;
```

Any help?

Comment: as you said in example: for `sal_id = 1` and `allowance_id = 4` won't the amount be `300` ?  and i think you'll get your answer if you try once more with your subquery manipulated . Try the subquery separately and get the concept of group by clear.

Comment: here amount is 300. but i want it to be sum of  allowances with id 5 and 6 , so 900 @Rex5

Comment: @ustaad - perhaps you meant 1000?  (400+200+250+150)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this query:

```
select salary_id, sum(amount) amount
from tmp_addit
where allowance_id in (5, 6)
group by salary_id
```

you get the sums that you want to add to the column `amount`.
Then you need to join this query to the table in an `UPDATE` statement:

```
update tmp_addit t
inner join (
  select salary_id, sum(amount) amount
  from tmp_addit
  where allowance_id in (5, 6)
  group by salary_id
) g on g.salary_id = t.salary_id
set t.amount = t.amount + g.amount
where t.allowance_id = 4;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ktjf942aDaNr7tZ9u9rdXK/1).
**Result**:

```
| addition_id | allowance_id | salary_id | amount |
| ----------- | ------------ | --------- | ------ |
| 1           | 4            | 1         | 900    |
| 2           | 5            | 1         | 400    |
| 3           | 6            | 1         | 200    |
| 4           | 4            | 2         | 700    |
| 5           | 5            | 2         | 250    |
| 6           | 6            | 2         | 150    |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a join on the aggregated query by the `sal_id`:

```
UPDATE tmp_addit t
JOIN   (SELECT sal_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
        FROM   tmp_addit
        WHERE  allowance_id IN (5, 6)) s ON t.sal_id = s.sal_id
SET    t.amount = t.amount + s.sum_amount
WHERE  allowance_id = 4
```

Comment: appreciate ur effort, but not exactly what i  want